# I want to advanced search technique from database by giving 2 textbox input and 2 dropdownlist input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use advanced search technique from database by giving 2 textbox input and 2 dropdownlist input in c#. If no input is given then nothing will be shown after hitting the search button. I have managed the technique to do search by giving 2 textbox string input but cant do it with both textbox and dropdownlist. Here's my code behind for search button.

```
public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
{


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fill_ddlPhone();
        fill_ddlEmail();
    }

}


private void fill_ddlPhone()
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";

        ddlPhone.Items.Clear();
        ddlPhone.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddlPhone.Items.Add(new ListItem("Phone", "-1"));
        ddlPhone.DataSource = cmscon.getRows(sql);
        ddlPhone.DataTextField = "Phone";
        ddlPhone.DataValueField = "Phone";
        ddlPhone.DataBind();
        ddlPhone.SelectedValue = "-1";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
private void fill_ddlEmail()
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";

        ddlEmail.Items.Clear();
        ddlEmail.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddlEmail.Items.Add(new ListItem("E-Mail", "-1"));
        ddlEmail.DataSource = cmscon.getRows(sql);
        ddlEmail.DataTextField = "Email";
        ddlEmail.DataValueField = "Email";
        ddlEmail.DataBind();
        ddlEmail.SelectedValue = "-1";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String str = "select * from registration where(FirstName like '%' + @search + '%'AND StudentID LIKE '%' + @StId + '%' )";



    SqlCommand cmdSearch = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    cmdSearch.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContactFirstName.Text;
    cmdSearch.Parameters.Add("@StId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContactID.Text;

    con.Open();
    cmdSearch.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmdSearch;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(ds, "FirstName");
    da.Fill(ds, "StudentID");
    gvSearch.DataSource = ds;
    gvSearch.DataBind();
    con.Close();





}
```

}

Comment: Just add 2 more paramters which you want in query and pass the values from the dropdown selected value.

Comment: added this..but doesnt work.

Comment: syntax for the query plz??thnx in advance

Comment: thats the way to be..thnx. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the following Stored Procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEARCH_REGITRATION]
    @FIRST_NAME varchar(50) = NULL,
    @EMAIL varchar(50) = NULL,
    @PHONE varchar(50) = NULL,
    @STUDENT_ID varchar(50) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@FIRST_NAME IS NULL AND @EMAIL IS NULL AND @PHONE IS NULL AND @STUDENT_ID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                [dbo].[Registration]
            WHERE
                @STUDENT_ID  = '-999'   -- Invalid value to return no results
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                [dbo].[Registration]
            WHERE
                (@FIRST_NAME IS NULL OR [FIRST_NAME] LIKE '%' + LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FIRST_NAME))) + '%')
                AND (@EMAIL IS NULL OR [EMAIL] LIKE '%' + LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@EMAIL))) + '%')
                AND (@PHONE IS NULL OR [PHONE] LIKE '%' + LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@PHONE))) + '%')
                AND (@STUDENT_ID IS NULL OR [STUDENT_ID] = @STUDENT_ID)
        END
END
GO
```

And call it via the followig C# code:

```
    public List<IRegistration> SearchRegistrations(string firstname, string email, string phone, string studentid)
    {
        List<IRegistration> result = new List<IRegistration>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ConnectionString);
        using (conn = GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SEARCH_REGITRATION]", conn);

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                Registration reg = new Registration();
                // Do property mappings here

                result.Add(ci);
            }
            rd.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: doesnt solve the issue..what is "ci"..stored procedure cannot be saved

Comment: These codes are just demonstration. I don't know your database and can not write exact code/query. You have to adapt it according to your needs.

Comment: i understand that. i adapted these code. according to my design of DB.But stored procedure cannot be saved

Comment: I hope you are not tryng to save it with the "Save" button in the menu. It is a creational script and all you have to do is to "Execute" it with F5.